# How old is the character SpongeBob SquarePants?

Tags: character, spongebob-squarepants

In the first SpongeBob SquarePants movie, SpongeBob stated that he has been employee of the month over 370 times. If you divide that by 12, that means he's been working at the Krusty Krab for over 30 years.

Let's not forget, SpongeBob was supposedly born on July 14, 1985. Today, that means he's in his 30's.

Additionally, he was supposedly 13 when he started working at the Krusty Krab.

With all these facts, the math kind of doesn't make sense.

If we stick with the theory that he started working at the Krusty Krab when he was 13, add 30+ years at the Krusty Krab and that means SpongeBob is in his 40's today.

So, how old is he?

Comment: Also, please don't reply to other users by editing their answer. Even though you lack sufficient rep to comment everywhere, you *always* have the ability to comment on answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

The age discrepancy is very deliberate. While he is now 30 years-old in human years, according to Stephen Hillenburg, he is a solid 50 in "SpongeBob years". The reasoning behind this is to emphasize his ageless immaturity.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpongeBob_SquarePants_(character)#Creation_and_design):

> Although SpongeBob's driver's license says his birthdate is July 14, 1985,[31] Hillenburg joked that he is fifty in "sponge years". He explained that **SpongeBob actually has no specific age**, but that he is old enough to be on his own and still be going to boating school.